# How to pass a parameter as string which include special character in flask app route

Tags: python, flask, routes

I want to pass "top3/1" as parameter in url. but it return 404 error.

here is my code:

```
@APP.route('/get_agent_details_on_voucher_code/<string:code>',methods=['GET'])
def get_agent_details_on_voucher_code(code):
    result = []
    if code == 'TOP3':
        voucher_earning_list = [{'voucher_code':'TOP3/1','agent_id':12345,'voucher_id':8}]
        if len(voucher_earning_list)>0:
            for item in voucher_earning_list:
                get_details = requests.get('http://192.168.1.55:5000/get_agent_details/'+str(item['agent_id']))
                get_result = get_details.json()
                if len(get_result) > 0:
                    get_ag_mobileno = get_result[0]['mobile']
                    result.append({'mobile_no':get_ag_mobileno,'agent_id':item['agent_id'],'voucher_id':item['voucher_id']})
                    response = jsonify(result)
                else:
                    response = jsonify(result)
        else:
            response = jsonify(result)
    else:
        response = jsonify(result)  
    return response
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, could you edit your question and use  proper formatting for the code snippet. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky question: generally with flask you have to specify the routes up to the final endpoint.

If you want to match all the sub routes you can use the type `path` instead of `string`, os you just need to change the route into:

`@APP.route('/get_agent_details_on_voucher_code/<path:code>',methods=['GET'])`

In this way you will obtain all the sub routes of `/get_agent_details_on_voucher_code/`, keep in mind the `code` will be a string, you have to extract the information you need parsing it.